# I have an old brain wallet phrase but no longer have program which converts it

Tags: wallet

I see brain wallet online but it uses mouse movement. All I want is a program where I enter the phrase and it gives me back both the public address and the private key. Ideally I should be able to download the software as opposed of course to entering the phrase online.